# Merge PDF and return as FileContentResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ActionResult that is working fine to return a PDF.

```
public ActionResult TrainingHours(int id)
    {
        EmployeeModel model = new EmployeeModel(id);
        if (!model.CheckEmployeeAccess())
            throw new HttpException(403, "Access Denied");

        byte[] report = model.GetTrainingHoursReport(id);
        return File(report, Constants.PdfMimeType, model.EmployeeHoursReportFileName);
    }
```

The byte[] is returned from a LocalReport's Render("PDF", DeviceInfoString) method and looks perfect when it is downloaded.

The customer wants to be able to click a link and have the same report run for a group of people and merged into one pdf for download.

```
  public ActionResult MassTrainingHours(int[] employeeIds)
    {
        if (employeeIds == null)
            return new EmptyResult();

        List<byte[]> reportsList = new List<byte[]>();
        foreach (int employeeId in employeeIds)
        {
            EmployeeModel model = new EmployeeModel(employeeId);
            reportsList.Add(model.GetTrainingHoursReport(employeeId));
        }
        Post.Domain.Services.PdfMerger merger = new Post.Domain.Services.PdfMerger();
        byte[] report = merger.MergeFiles(reportsList);

        return File(report, Constants.PdfMimeType, "TrainingHours.pdf");
```

Here's my class that merges the pdfs using iTextSharp.

```
public class PdfMerger
{
    public byte[] MergeFiles(List<byte[]> inputFiles)
    {
        MemoryStream outputMS = new MemoryStream();
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, outputMS);
        writer.CloseStream = false;

        PdfImportedPage page = null;

        document.Open();

        foreach (byte[] fileData in inputFiles)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileData);
            int n = reader.NumberOfPages;

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                writer.AddPage(page);
            }

            PRAcroForm form = reader.AcroForm;
            if (form != null)
                writer.CopyAcroForm(reader);
        }

        document.Close();

        return outputMS.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This all seems to run with no errors but I get absolutely nothing returned from the ActionResult.

If I use the MergeFiles method slightly modified to a FileStream on a winforms application the process runs smoothly and I get the output file I'm looking for.